# Fastlane iOS error: No profile for team 'team_id' matching 'com.companyname.appname'

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I am facing this error from few days and I am unable to release the .ipa file manually also due to this issue

> error: No profile for team 'team_id' matching 'com.companyname.appname' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'team_id/com.companyname.appname'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'TargetName' from project 'ProjectName')

Earlier I was able to build and submit the app using the same provisioning profile.

This is my beta name in fastfile

```
lane :beta do   
    version = get_version_number(target: 'TargetName')
    get_certificates           # invokes cert
    get_provisioning_profile   # invokes sigh
    
    increment_version_number(version_number: version)   
    increment_version_number(bump_type: 'patch')
   
    build_app(workspace: "ProjectName.xcworkspace", scheme: "SchemeName", skip_profile_detection: true )
    upload_to_testflight
   
  end
```

> Note my code signing is set to MANUAL

I was able to submit the app to test flight with the same configuration mentioned above but suddenly it stopped working.

I have tried following to fix the issue

1. I have checked the code singing it is as the fastlane document suggests.
2. I have changed the folder permission to allow the access to all users.
3. I have given permission to user where the provisioning profiles are stored.
4. i have tried wrapping the build code in gym()

```
   Dir.chdir('../Pods') do
      disable_automatic_code_signing(
      path: 'ProjectName.xcodeproj',
      team_id: 'team_id',
      targets: ['TargetName'],
      profile_name: 'com.companyname.appname'
    )
      gym(workspace: 'ProjectName.xcworkspace',scheme: "SchemeName", clean: true)    
    upload_to_testflight
   end
```

5. I have also tried moving the Provisioning Profiles folder to automatically create a new one. using the following command `mv ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles ~/Library/MobileDevice/Old\ Provisioning\ Profile`  Even with the newly created Provisioning profile the problem still persists

Still unable to resolve the issue.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Due to running fastlane with sudo privileges the folder permissions had changed, I was not sure which folder so i had to reinstall Mac OS. The issue no longer exists.

Answer (score 4):

The error might be vary, and could not be a signing issue at all.

Sometimes the issue could be a permission issue, That because at first time ran `fastlane` command with `sudo`,

**So what I can say...** ***"Don't execute any shell commands with `sudo` at first time, If there are permission issue, then that you can try with `sudo`."***

Here, check the write permission for the following folders **`don't use sudo`**, and if not have proper write permission grant write permission for all users.

1. `/Users/{user}/Library/Logs/gym/`
2. `/Users/{user}/Library/Logs/gym/XXX.log`
3. `./fastlane/`
4. `./fastlane/report.xml`

Comment: 10 hours at least I am on this. This is crazy. is it not possible that fast lane state the permission error?

Answer (score 1):

often this error will happen if the xcode project is set to Automatically manage signing.

To check, open the xCode project, click on your target, select the option called *Signing and Capabilities* and make sure that the checkbox *Automatically manage signing* is not checked.

Once you have unchecked it, make sure to select a valid provisioning profile from the drop down list *Provisioning Profile*.

Best,
Jorge